# How to access the Index Of A Generic.List By Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, list, generics

ok, ive a class and i pass an object as property.

the object that i pass is a `List<X>`

in my class im trying to access the Object index by reflection BUT I CAN'T!!!

Example:

this class works i just wrote down the part i want to show you and i need help.

```
class MyClass
{
    private object _recordSet;
    public object RecordSet
    {
        get { return _recordSet; }
        set { _recordSet = value; }
    }

    public string Draw()
    {
        system.reflection.Assembly asem = system.reflection.Assembly.getAssembly(_dataSource.GetType());

        object instance;

        instance = asem.CreateInstance(_dataSource.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType.FullName);

        //to access de Count of my List
        int recordcount = int.Parse(_dataSource.GetType().GetProperty("Count").GetValue(_dataSource,null));

        //i need to do a 
        for(int cont = 0; cont < recordCount; cont++)
        {
            _dataSource[cont].Name; // <-- THIS PART IS NOT WORKING!!! because i cant access the Index Directly.... WHAT TO DO!! ???
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as to what you're asking, so I've deleted my answer. Odds are all you need to do is cast the object to List<T>. More than likely your code has other issues if you're casting to-from object though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using reflection (and hence lots of `object`), why not just cast as an `IList` (non-generic) instead?

i.e.

```
IList list = (IList)actualList;
object foo = list[17];
```

Also - for your original code with `Count`, you don't mean `int.Parse` - you should just cast (since we expect `Count` to be an `int`).

Comment: Add: if (actualList is IList)

Comment: @Jeff B - I disagree; the scenario suggests that we expect it to be a list, hence if the data *isn't* an IList, I'm happy for it to raise an exception. It depends on the scenario, of course; if it was ad-hoc data-binding to either an object, an IList or an IListSource, then "as"/"is" is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast your object to a list first, you don't need reflection here.